# I got red flags on the last part of the code

Tags: java

```
    public static void main(string[] args) {
    pr10({0,-1},{4,3};)
   }
   }
```

I got red flags on the last part of the code, and it says:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error, insert ")" to complete SingleMemberAnnotation
    - Syntax error on token "pr10", @ expected before this token
    - Syntax error on token "}", delete this token
    - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete MemberValueArrayInitializer
    - Syntax error, insert "VariableDeclarators" to complete 
     LocalVariableDeclaration
    - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete BlockStatements
    - Syntax error, insert "SimpleName" to complete Name
```

Comment: What do you mean by red flags? Explain the problem at hand properly

Comment: These are the errors I got:Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error, insert ")" to complete SingleMemberAnnotation
 - Syntax error on token "pr10", @ expected before this token
 - Syntax error on token "}", delete this token
 - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete MemberValueArrayInitializer
 - Syntax error, insert "VariableDeclarators" to complete 
  LocalVariableDeclaration
 - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete BlockStatements
 - Syntax error, insert "SimpleName" to complete Name...

Comment: Edit the question and Add the errors in the question itself

Comment: Your posted code has a `pr9`, no `pr10` is here.

Comment: That is not debugging.  That does not come until the compiler actually compiles your code.  Take small steps and try to understand the first error reported by the compiler.

Comment: Yeh guys pro10 is class name..

Comment: @GovindaKc you mentioned `pro10` whereas in code it is `pr10`.

Comment: I just edited and posted @Balwinder Singh. I am new here so also learing the things how to use it. Thank you.

Comment: Like already mentioned by @ElliottFrisch you need to look into `pr10({0,-1},{4,3};)` line. For starters, you don't have a pr10 method in your code and the rest of the compilation errors are syntax based. So focus onto this line and try to find out what you are missing

Answer (score 0):

This

```
pr10({0,-1},{4,3};)
```

Is meaningless. You wanted to invoke the `pr9` function. It takes two `double[]` arguments. There isn't an inline short form for array initialization. Change the line to

```
pr9(new double[] { 0, -1 }, new double[] { 4, 3 });
```

And I get

```
[-12.0,12.0]
```

Comment: @GovindaKc: additionally, your semi-colon was not at the end of the statement - it was inside the last bracket. Don't forget to accept Elliot's answer when the system allows you to do so.